# (wrong-type-argument stringp custom-variable-set) Error when setting variable

Tags: variables, customization

I'm having an issue setting custom Emacs variables. When I try to set the variable pressing <kbd>STATE</kbd> I run into this error:  `(wrong-type-argument stringp custom-variable-set)`
This is the full debugger stack :

```
 substitute-command-keys(custom-variable-set)
  widget-choose(#("Operation on Python Shell Interpreter" 13 37 (custom-data python-shell-interpreter)) (keymap (custom-variable-set menu-item "Set for Current Session" custom-variable-set :enable (eq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-state) 'modified)) (custom-variable-save menu-item "Save for Future Sessions" custom-variable-save :enable (memq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-state) '(modified set changed rogue))) (custom-redraw menu-item "Undo Edits" custom-redraw :enable (memq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-state) '(modified changed))) (custom-variable-reset-saved menu-item "Revert This Session's Customization" custom-variable-reset-saved :enable (memq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-state) '(modified set changed rogue))) (custom-variable-reset-standard menu-item "Erase Customization" custom-variable-reset-standard :enable (memq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-state) '(modified set changed saved rogue))) (custom-variable-reset-backup menu-item "Set to Backup Value" custom-variable-reset-backup :enable (get (widget-value custom-actioned-widget) 'backup-value)) (sep0 menu-item "---") (custom-comment-show menu-item "Add Comment" custom-comment-show :enable (custom-comment-invisible-p custom-actioned-widget)) (sep1 menu-item "---") (custom-variable-edit menu-item "Show Current Value" custom-variable-edit :button (:radio eq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-form) 'edit)) (custom-variable-edit-lisp menu-item "Show Saved Lisp Expression" custom-variable-edit-lisp :button (:radio eq (widget-get custom-actioned-widget :custom-form) 'lisp))) nil)
  (let* ((completion-ignore-case t) (custom-actioned-widget widget) (answer (widget-choose (concat "Operation on " (custom-unlispify-tag-name (widget-get widget :value))) (if custom-variable-menu (custom-menu-filter custom-variable-menu widget) custom-variable-extended-menu) event))) (if answer (funcall answer widget)))
  (if (eq (widget-get widget :custom-state) 'hidden) (custom-toggle-hide widget) (if (eq (widget-get widget :custom-state) 'modified) nil (custom-variable-state-set widget)) (custom-redraw-magic widget) (let* ((completion-ignore-case t) (custom-actioned-widget widget) (answer (widget-choose (concat "Operation on " (custom-unlispify-tag-name (widget-get widget :value))) (if custom-variable-menu (custom-menu-filter custom-variable-menu widget) custom-variable-extended-menu) event))) (if answer (funcall answer widget))))
  custom-variable-action((custom-variable :group ... :tag ... :custom-prefixes ... :custom-level 2 :value python-shell-interpreter :parent ... :indent ...) nil)
  widget-apply((custom-variable :group ... :tag ... :custom-prefixes ... :custom-level 2 :value python-shell-interpreter :parent ... :indent ...) :action nil)
  widget-parent-action((custom-magic :args ... :parent ... :indent 0 :children ... :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 3993 in *Customize Group: Python*> :to #<marker at 4072 in *Customize Group: Python*> :buttons ...) nil)
  widget-apply((custom-magic :args ... :parent ... :indent 0 :children ... :from #<marker (moves after insertion) at 3993 in *Customize Group: Python*> :to #<marker at 4072 in *Customize Group: Python*> :buttons ...) :action nil)
  widget-parent-action((choice-item :help-echo "Change the sta..." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent ...) nil)
  widget-apply((choice-item :help-echo "Change the sta..." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent ...) :action nil)
  widget-apply-action((choice-item :help-echo "Change the sta..." :format "%[%t%]" :button-prefix widget-push-button-prefix :button-suffix widget-push-button-suffix :mouse-down-action widget-magic-mouse-down-action :tag " State " :parent ...) nil)
  (if button (widget-apply-action button event) (error "You can't edit this part of the Custom buffer"))
  (let ((button (get-char-property pos 'button))) (or button (if (setq button (get-char-property (line-beginning-position) 'button)) (or (eq (widget-type button) 'custom-group-link) (setq button nil)))) (if button (widget-apply-action button event) (error "You can't edit this part of the Custom buffer")))
  Custom-newline(3996)
  funcall-interactively(Custom-newline 3996)
  call-interactively(Custom-newline nil nil)
  command-execute(Custom-newline)
```

Comment: 1. Do you see the problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. 2. Provide a step-by-step recipe to specify the problem. IOW, state clearly what you did, to get the error.

Comment: If difficult to state what you did clearly, GIF please.